# How do I instruct my daughter to drink water from a bottle from 'up'!

Tags: word-request, word-usage

In our region, we see this as manners. Suppose there is only ***one*** bottle of water and we are four people including my daughter.

And she has a habit of drinking it by **touching the bottle with her lips... like this**

[image: drinking with lips touching]

But then, others are also there. So, I advise her **not to drink that way.**

I advise her that you must drink **without touching your lips... like this -**

[image: Courtesy: yaymicro; no lips touching]

How do I advise her in good English?

I use...

> Drink water from ***up!***

Is it funny? or proper?

Comment: Sounds funny. Any reason not to explain simply that she shouldn't touch the bottle with her lips? Whith my children giving a reason usually works best.

Comment: "from up" makes me think of the person hovering over the bottle...

Comment: Regarding the "parenting aspect", not the language: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49766/who-added-water-to-my-chowder/49770#comment72332_49770 -> see the comment section of my answer for how to teach kids not to double- dip.

Comment: "Pour water in your mouth from **above**", maybe, but it sounds somewhat technical.

Comment: @CopperKettle it can also be `Drink water from above` why `pour water in your mouth from above?`

Comment: @sharon - I used "pour" because it creates an image of free-falling water. I thought one can *drink* from above and still touch the mouth of the bottle.

Comment: @Stephie **To explain only**, I need a proper word. *"Darling, drink water from 'up', others are also there!"*

Comment: @MaulikV: So how about "Darling, don't touch the bottle, ..." if she only needs a reminder.

Comment: I think it partially depends on how old she is and what level of English can she understand.

Comment: Maybe there is some familiar analogy you can employ, like "darling, use the bottle as a [watering pot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watering_can), let the water drop from above".

Comment: @Copper - I think you've nailed it with _pour_; I'd say: _"Pour the water into your mouth – don't drink from the bottle"_. (No need for the "from above" part; pouring water won't defy gravity.)

Comment: Thank you, @J.R.! You can post an answer: you've formulated it better, and I'm busy reading up on [the more](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/what-are-sentences-like-the-longer-x-the-more-y-called-and-can-they-be-used-i/3945#3945) (0:

Comment: @Stephie "Darling, don't touch the bottle" ~ Aw, dad, how do I pick the bottle then! haha :P

Comment: @CoolHandLouis She's 9, and most importantly **a non-native**.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words.

If I was training my daughter in the etiquette of sharing water from the same bottle, I'd probably say something along the lines of:

> Pour the water into your mouth, like this –

and at this point, I would **demonstrate**, and then I would elaborate with a clarifying remark, such as:

> – and don't let the bottle touch your lips

or:

> – and don't put your mouth on the bottle

This method has two advantages:

- first, it shows her ***visually*** what you are trying to do,
- second, if she messes up and spills the water, or puts her mouth on the bottle, you've already had your sip :^)

Incidentally, this takes some skill. It might be best to exercise some foresight and have the child practice the technique at home. Until the skill is mastered, you can simply give the bottle to your child *last* and let her drink the remainder in the normal way. (But this is not [parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/); I'm digressing now.)